# High RAM eaters in Ubuntu servers

Tags: server, ram

actually what are the High RAM eaters in Ubuntu server , is there any such things ? 
I just want to know . If there , i want to remove them because i need to save RAM . I will use Different servers (3-4) and each one going to have its specific application .so remaining all services i don't want to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **top** command. From within top, press `O` (that's shift + the letter o), then `n`, then press `Enter` - it will now be sorted by memory usage

Comment: You can just press Shift+M without going into the options menu, to get the same result, btw. :)

Answer (score 1):

It usually depends on what you are running exactly. Basic apache, postgres, or other services don't really use a lot of RAM not doing anything. But if you have very large databases, and poorly written/designed web pages, which are getting loaded constantly, then those services can start consuming more and more resources.